# From .py to .exe with Kivy Python 3 and external library

Tags: python, kivy

I have made a program in Python which has two files. It has a python file (main file), and a kivy file which grabs a few images from the same directory. I also have used an external library located in a different folder with several dll and py files.

Now I want to convert this main python file into an exe, with everything working. I have tried to use auto py to exe multiple times (no kivy and external library, only external library, one file, one directory, etc), which is basically PyInstaller with a nice GUI. It worked to put it in one directory WITHOUT the kivy related stuff. But I want to have everything working (so main python file + kivy and pictures + external library) into a single exe file, rather than a whole directory.
I have also searched far and wide across the web, but can't find any solution.

I would greatly appreciate any kind of help!

Kind regards,

The Lion

Comment: I suspect you need to use the `Additional Files` capability to add your `kv` file and your images.

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't work. For example with the external library it does work when I create a whole directory with the exe, but not when there's just a single exe. There's something wrong with when I have to locate the dll files in a separate folder of this library. No idea how I could make it so I don't have a whole directory.

Comment: Under the "Advanced" tag, try the "--add-binary" option for the `dll`.

Comment: Do I have to just add the path where the dll is located? So for example `C:\Users\Downloads\file.dll`? Or something different?

Comment: In the "--add-binary" field add "C:\Users\Downloads\file.dll;.". The ";" is a separator, and the "." says copy the dll to the same directory as your main python script. How does your app load the dll? You may have to consider if your app will find the dll in that directory.